# TabOrder not working

Tags: c#-4.0, combobox, textbox, tablelayoutpanel, tab-ordering

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 and I was trying to put  tab order to my `textbox` and `combobox` controls.

The controls are put inside a `TableLayoutPanel` and its very difficult to select `tab order` for the controls.

Is there any better way to set the `tab order`?

[image: Without <code>Tab Order</code>]

[image: with 'Tab Order' key pressed]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a nice article on [Automatic Runtime Tab Order Management for Windows Forms](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8406/Automatic-Runtime-Tab-Order-Management-for-Windows). This dll can be downloaded and imported for any application. It provides vertical and horizontal `Tab Order`. Works fine with me. :)